# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, tic-tac-toe, react-dom

I created a react app using **npx create-react-app** and made a folder named components and inside that I created a Javascript file with the title of Game.js, which basically **returns a simple JSX saying with a div having the text of *"Game"***. I imported it in App.js file (which gets imported to index.js and the index.js renders it to the index.html using reactDOM). But when I try to do this simple task, the compiler throws me the **error** stating...

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/Game.js
  Line 8:1:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Here is the **App.js** file

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Game from "./components/Game";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Game />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is the **Game.js** which is inside the components folder...

```
import React from "react";

function Game() {
  return <div>Game</div>;
}

export default Game;
```

And the **index.js** is as follows [edit: Added after request from comment]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Any help shall be appreciated.

Comment: Everything looks fine. How your `index.js` looks like?

Comment: @Dupocas I've previously worked with react, and this is exactly the procedure I followed. Even I'm confused. I've added the index.js in the original post for further reference.

Comment: @Dupocas is right. With the code you're showing now the problem is not reproducible.

Comment: This is probably a configuration issue either in the `ReactDOM` call ir your configuration itself (babel and webpack) but  since you've installed via `create-react-app` it's probably a local configuration. Have you tried reinstall via `yarn create react-app` (or similar) to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: I'm also thinking on the same lines. I tired restarting vscode. And I deleted the node modules and package.json and then reinstalled with npm install. Same issue.

Comment: Thank you @Dupocas I finally got it working. Seems like it was somesort of a werid bug, that got fixed on restarting my laptop and reinitialising the server. Now it's up and working and says compiled with no errors. I dont think reinstall was necessary, but if anyone in the future faces this sort of an issue, reinitialise/reset your development server (localhost, in my case).